# discord.py Problem : How to check the first user that joined in voice chat in discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I am making a bot that it do like when people joined in specific VC. It'll create new voice channel by using who joined in that specific vc first. Don't mind my english I know my english suck. :c
I was trying on this

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord 
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">")
client = discord.Client()

@commands.command()
async def join_voice(self, ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if connected:
      await create_voice_channel("I want to add a person who triggered the bot by join specific VC to  set name of new VC to their name.")
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `on_voice_state_update` coroutine function. I'm not quite sure what you want to do with the data which is passed to the function, but you can probably find what you want [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.on_voice_state_update).

For any other issues, try checking the [discord.py API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#)